# Load different </iframe> depending on user's screen width

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe, responsive-design

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and help the Internets out with your response(s) in the process.

I have a responsive website that runs on WordPress 4.0.1.

After creating a Page and posting content to it, I noticed one of the iframes I posted is not responsive and does not look good on mobile devices with small screens (iPhone 4/4S/5/5S). Even though I used the vendor's solution via CSS to make the iframe responsive, it still does not render as nice in mobile devices with small screens.

So I went ahead and created different iframes for each mobile device screen.

Now I would like the ability to put some code on my page that will **detect the user's screen horizontal resolution and load the iframe that would best fit that resolution**.

For example,

IF User Screen is less than 305
THEN

IFRAME for iPhone 5S

ELSE IF
IF User Screen is less than 355
THEN

IFRAME for iPhone 6

ELSE

IFRAME THAT SUPPORTS ALL OTHER WIDTHS

What would be the best way to accomplish this using WordPress?

I tried re-using the code in the two resolutions below with my own iframes, and they did not work:

http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/198521-help-if-else-statement-loading-iframe-based-resolution.html

[Load Iframe based on screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256742/load-iframe-based-on-screen-width)

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You actually don't need any javascript at all.  You can do this entirely with CSS.   Just use CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANK YOU all for taking the time to post your answers, unfortunately, they did not work for me, and it may be due to my lack of understanding Web/CSS programming.

After spending a few hours doing some more research, the code below worked for me:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var iPhone5S ='<iframe src="https://www.YOUR_IFRAME_URL_GOES_HERE.COM" width="305" height="860"></iframe>';
var iPhone6 = '<iframe src="https://www.YOUR_IFRAME_URL_GOES_HERE.COM" width="354" height="860"></iframe>';
var Web = '<iframe src="https://www.YOUR_IFRAME_URL_GOES_HERE.COM" width="940" height="970"></iframe>';

if (document.width < 321)
{document.write (iPhone5S)}
else if (document.width < 376)
{document.write (iPhone6)}
else
{document.write (Web)}

</script>
```

The code works like this:

**var** declares the name/device type and its corresponding iframe, then the **IF** statement, based on the document width returns the iframe you declared to match the user screen width.

Hope this helps the internets as much as it helped me!

Comment: your solution isn't reliable, please take your time and learn a bit about css and media queries

Comment: The solution works for me in my environment, that's why I marked as the correct answer. Your comment is not reliable as it does not explain why my answer is not reliable.

Comment: to start off, you are ignoring everyone without a support for JavaScript. media queries allow you to handle screen rotation and resizing etc, your script loads a view and sticks to that

Comment: This code proved helpful in a very specific situation. A client with a low budget for rebuilding their site decided to rebuild in Weebly with iframing into certain functionality of their old site. (Not idea, but not my decision.) They want the content in the iframes to scale to at least one phone size. (Again, not idea, but not my decision.) 

Weebly does not have an efficient interface for adding JavaScript, but I was finally able to get this code to work with some adjustments.

1. Document.width is deprecated, so I used document.body.clientWidth
2. I didn't use variables, but I'm over

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple non-javascript solution, you can do this with CSS Media Queries at the end of your CSS file.  (Perhaps easier if you're using WP).

eg:  ( from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ )

```
   /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Set the default "display" styles of your iFrames to none.  Then use the styles in the above media queries to set **display:block;** for the iframe you want to show.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Bangkokian, but I am not that familiar with CSS. In the WordPress template I purchased, in order for me to add custom CSS, I have to add it in a special place - adding it to the actual page/post will not generate it correctly. Where in your code do I enter the <iframe> code for each screen resolution?

Comment: I can't see how setting the screensize will load a different iframe. Setting a layer to hidden doesn't exclude it from the HTML, it just hides the content on the screen. So, all content loads. Or, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use `fitvids.js` it's the better solution , it take care of all your `iframes` what ever the screen resolution here is an example i made it for you :

**A lightweight, easy-to-use jQuery plugin for fluid width video embeds.**

**[OFFICIAL WEB PAGE](http://fitvidsjs.com/)**

**[LIVE DEMO](http://codepen.io/zerubeus/pen/qEKLvo)**

```
<div class="container">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SZEflIVnhH8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="container-2">
        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/23534361" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/23534361">The Animated Envato Community Podcast</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/activetuts">Activetuts+</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <iframe src="http://demo-video-site.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="custom"></iframe>
    </div>
```

don't forget to add Jquery and `FitVids.js`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.map"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fitvids/1.1.0/jquery.fitvids.min.js"></script>
```

With this **Jquery** plugin you don't have to set different media queries for each resolution the plugin do all the job for you !

## EDIT :

to load a different `iframe` depend on the screen size, here is a `jQuery` solution  :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
if($(window).width() < 1500)
  $('#IFRAMEID').attr("src","Your URL");
else
  $('#IFRAMEID').attr("src","Your URL");
});

</script>
```

you may be need to add id's to your iframes like follow :

```
<iframe id="IFRAMEID" src="public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-iPhone5S-P/…; width="305" height="870"></iframe> 

<iframe id="IFRAMEID" src="public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-Web-Automatic/…; width="940" height="970"></iframe>
```

Comment: Ze Rubeus, thanks for the response. But where in the code do I tell it to show a specific iframe for the specific screen width. I cannot use 1 iframe and resize it, as the content will not be displayed correctly on mobile devices.

Comment: the plugin will adapt your iframe to what ever screen resolution so you don't have to manage this your self

Comment: you want to show different iframe is specific screen width ??

Comment: Correct, I want to show a different iframe for each device screen width

Comment: Great, thank you so much Ze Rebeus, this is more or less what I am looking for the script to accomplish:

IF User Screen is less than 305, THEN display IFRAME for iPhone 5S; ELSE IF IF User Screen is less than 355, THEN display IFRAME for iPhone 6; ELSE Display IFRAME THAT SUPPORTS ALL OTHER WIDTHS

Comment: i updated my answer , use this Jquery code and you will be able to change the iframe depend on the device screen size

Comment: I posted the code below to the WordPress page, but it shows up blank:    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
if($(window).width() < 400)
  $('#IFRAMEID').attr("src","https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-iPhone5S-P/iPhone-5S-P?amp;:embed=y&amp;:toolbar=no&amp;:display_count=no&amp;:showVizHome=no&amp:style=display:none");
else
  $('#IFRAMEID').attr("src","https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-Web-Automatic/Dashboard?amp;:embed=y&amp;:toolbar=no&amp;:display_count=no&amp;:showVizHome=no&amp:style=display:none");
});
</script>

Comment: you need to change this $('#IFRAMEID') depend in your iframe class or id

Comment: This is my iframe code, what would be the class or ID ?  <iframe src="https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-iPhone5S-P/iPhone-5S-P?amp;:embed=y&amp;:toolbar=no&amp;:display_count=no&amp;:showVizHome=no&amp:style=display:none" width="305" height="870"></iframe>

        
<iframe src="https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-Web-Automatic/Dashboard?amp;:embed=y&amp;:toolbar=no&amp;:display_count=no&amp;:showVizHome=no&amp:style=display:none" width="940" height="970"></iframe>

Comment: there is no id with your iframes you need to add one like so

Comment: <iframe id="IFRAMEID" src="public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-iPhone5S-P/…; width="305" height="870"></iframe> <iframe id="IFRAMEID"  src="public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-Web-Automatic/…; width="940" height="970"></iframe>

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a dummy, but I am lost. How would the code look if my iframes are the ones below? Can you please update the answer with it? <iframe src="https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-iPhone5S-P/iPhone-5S-P?amp;:embed=y&amp;:toolbar=no&amp;:display_count=no&amp;:showVizHome=no&amp:style=display:none" width="305" height="870"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Resume-Dashboard-Web-Automatic/Dashboard?amp;:embed=y&amp;:toolbar=no&amp;:display_count=no&amp;:showVizHome=no&amp:style='display:none" width="940" height="970"></iframe>

Comment: what should go under the "Your URL", the entire code for the <iframe> or just the url to the content?

Comment: just the url of the content

Comment: Ze Rebus, I've been trying to get this to work, but it does not. It seems like the function is not working.